# EditText is hidden by the softkeyboard in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, window-soft-input-mode

I have a layout in an app with parallax effect on an edittext, my problem is **when I tap on the edittext softkeyboard hides my editext?**Can anybody please help me for this, I have searched for it and found about "WindowsoftInputmode" which is not working in my case.

**Code in manifest**

```
<activity
            android:name="one.tusk.stush.activities.NewPostDetailActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan" >
```

Comment: i tried it . It is not working in my case too. so i removed the  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan" this line then it is adjusting my layout according to keyboard

Comment: please see my answer...

Comment: @Dhiraj -bro can you help me by any refrence?

Comment: @sulphuricAcid actully this should not happen if you are using android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan" but i dont know why it is giving such a weird behaviour

Comment: @sulphuricAcid after reading ur q i tried with one edittext with android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan" property but it wont work in my case too.so i tried it with removing this property and it works but dont know why

Comment: @sulphuricAcid please check my answer it's working in my case...!!!!!

Comment: @sulphuricAcid Just try to replace this `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"` in your `Manifest`.

Comment: plz see my edited answer....:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`.

If this is not enough, you might need to add the property `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to the root layout containing your EditText.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your manifest,

```
<activity
        android:name=".rapcalsy.MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Change your layout according this,
dont miss the line which is

`android:isScrollContainer="true"`

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:stretchColumns="*">
        ...
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this out.

Set an **android:softInputMode** attribute to **adjustResize** in Manifest and put the parent layout inside a **ScrollView**. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I tried a bit with as you said then i got this working 
                    edit the your manifest file

```
    <activity
                android:name="one.tusk.stush.activities.NewPostDetailActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" >
```

and then add below line of code in oncreate of java class

```
 getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

So that keyboard will not shown to you directly/always

Comment: But the problem he has is not about hiding or showing keyboard. it's about whenever softkeyboard appears it hides his edit text.

Comment: @jaydroider it is also not hiding editText in my case